# Why is my Hadoop MapReduce doesn't run faster even when i add nodes on the cluster?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

So i run a 50 MB of data with WordCount on my Hadoop cluster. i run the test  on 5 different cluster size, single-node cluster up to 5 node cluster. The thing is, the execution time isn't changing much. it only have 1 - 2 minutes different on each run. isn't adding node to a cluster result in more resource that can be used and making the job run faster?

i expect the execution time to be much more faster with each node addition, but the result showing me otherwise.

the node i use have 2 GB of RAM and 2 cores. 
i don't change anything regarding container on yarn-site.xml and map/reduce allocation.mb on mapred-site.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to test it with a bigger amount of data.
YARN will allocate a map container for each HDFS block of data. The default HDFS block size is usually 64Mb, so perhaps your test file only uses one HDFS block.
A container is the minimum slice of computation that YARN will assign to a node. In the worst case for your testing, it will need only one container for the map phase, and another for the reduce phase. 2 containers usually fits in just one node, so adding more nodes doesn't give you more speed.

Comment: So if i have 256 MB of data and 64 MB of block size, Hadoop will split the file into 4 blocks and file will be worked on 4 nodes?

Comment: Not directly, because the same node can execute several YARN containers at the same time. It depends on the amount of memory each node has, and the default container size